# gzip write newline to file python

Tags: python

I am trying to write an iterable of tuples to a file using gzip in python. But when I write the new line character (\n)

```
For example:
   if the iterable of tuples is like this: [(1,2,3) , (4,5)]
   the output file should be : 1,2,3
                               4,5

   but I got: 1,2,34,5



   I dont know where is my newline character gone!!!

   Here is my code: 
      fi = gzip.open(filename, "wb")
      for tup in data:
        fi.write(','.join(str(x) for x in tup).encode("utf-8"))
        fi.write("\n".encode("utf-8"))
      fi.close()
```

Comment: Please include the definition of `data`. The snippet of code you shows does exactly what it is intended to do, so I suspect the problem lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible that you're opening the file with an editor that recognizes only `\r\n` as a newline.

Comment: @bernie : agreed. I'd venture to guess they are on Windows and possibly opened the uncompressed file in Notepad. Notepad is rtaher dumb. If it doesn't see \r\n then it doesn't see a newline. \n by itself is simple ignored. Wordpad and most other editors are smart enough to do the conversion automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only assume that there is a problem with the way you are reading or displaying the uncompressed data? I tried this following code on Windows and Linux (Python 2.7) and it did work:

```
import gzip

filename = 'gzipout.gz'
data =  [(1,2,3) , (4,5)]
fi = gzip.open(filename, 'wb')
for tup in data:
    fi.write(','.join(str(x) for x in tup).encode("utf-8"))
    fi.write('\n'.encode("utf-8"))
fi.close()

fi = gzip.open(filename, 'rb')
unzipdata = fi.read()
print unzipdata
fi.close()
```

The output was:

```
1,2,3
4,5
```

This code simply gzips the contents to a file and then reads back the compressed data and dumps it to the console as is. The newline is present.

If I use `gunzip gzipout.gz` it extracts to gzipout and if I display the contents the newline is also present.

Your behavior isn't uncommon especially if you use an old brain dead program to open the uncompressed text file. In the *nix world an end of line (EOL) is *generally* denoted by `\n`. In Windows EOL is represented by two characters `\r\n` . Python has a *universal* mode for writing text so that it automatically converts `\n` to whatever EOL is on the platform. Unfortunately GZIP still doesn't seem to honor that flag with Python 2.7. This means that even if you opened a GZIP file for writing with mode "U" (Text mode + universal) no translation is done on each write.

If you are on a Windows platform and targeting Windows users then you might consider the non-portable solution of explicitly writing '\r\n' so that brain-dead editors like Notepad will render properly. I am guessing that something like this would yield the results you are looking for:

```
for tup in data:
    fi.write(','.join(str(x) for x in tup).encode("utf-8"))
    fi.write('\r\n'.encode("utf-8")) # notice I use \r\n instead of \n
fi.close()
```